# Django, different result between `all()` method and `all().values()` method

Tags: python, django

I am facing this problem, where i can't access the url of some image using `values()` method, but it still can be accessed if it is a queryset object rather than a pythonic list:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(length=100)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='media') # the image is stored in aws, hence it will produce a url
    def __str__(self):
      return f"{self.img.url}"
```

this is example model, now let's try printing that on the shell:

```py
>>models.MyModel.objects.all()
<QuerySet[{'img':'https://aws/bucketlist.com/some_img.png'}]>
```

however with `values()` method:

```py
>>models.MyModel.objects.all().values()
<QuerySet[{'img':'media/some_img.png'}]>
```

as you can see with `values()` i get the local path rather than the url to the aws cloud

note that aws storage is set correctly in django.

settings.py:

```py
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'  

MEDIA_ROOT  = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')


CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "/media"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')  

AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')  

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME') 

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False  

AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None  

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'   

AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = "ap-southeast-2"  

AWS_S3_ADDRESSING_STYLE = "virtual"
```

however, images are appearing on AWS and it seem to be fine on the cloud side.

UPDATE, based on the comments of my post:

here is how i serialize my model:

```py
class MyModelSerializers(serializer.Serializer):
      class Meta:
           fields = '__all__'
           model = models.MyModel
```

a view would look like this:

```py
class MyModelView(views.APIView):
     serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
     def post(self,request):
          data =MyModelSerializer(data=request.data)
          if data.is_valid():
             name = data.data['name']
             return Response(models.MyModel.objects.filter(name=name).values()) # if this is without `values()` it will give me `JsonResponse` is not serializable error
```

Comment: This is indeed the expected behavior: the `.values()` will use the data as specified in the database. This is one of the many reasons *not* to use `.values()`: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/over-use-of-values.html

Comment: however, in my case i really need to use `values()`, because i need to send the response to the client side and i need to play with the data on the frontend. I need to say that my frontend is React, so i am not using template rendering here

Comment: that is where you should use a serializer. Normally using values should only be done for a very limited number of use-cases like GROUP BYs on arbitrary fields: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

Comment: a serializer is already there, the problem that arise is that `Json` like response can't be serialized. (in my case the queryset instance)

Comment: can you share the view and the serializer logic. Likely the problem is there, falling back to using `.values()` is *not* a good idea at all.

Comment: code example is updated.

Comment: But you do not use the serializer at all: you made a custom implementation of `get`, and thus the serializer is omitted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249376/discussion-between-ghazi-and-willem-van-onsem).

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the very *many* reasons not to use `.values()` in the first place: this will make a database query, and then transform the items in dictionaries, and thus losing all model logic attached to it. This thus means that `.img` will no longer return a `FieldFile` object, but a simple string, and thus show the path relative to the media root, not the entire URL as is normally done through the `FieldFile`.

Your `MyModelView` also does not work with the serializer at all: you simply made an implementation of `get`, and thus there is no logic that works with the serializer.

Likely the easiest way is just work with a [**`ListAPIView`** <sup>[classy-drf]</sup>](https://www.cdrf.co/3.1/rest_framework.generics/ListAPIView.html):

```
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView


class MyModelView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
    queryset = models.MyModel.objects.all()
```

or you can patch the `get_queryset` method:

```
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView


class MyModelView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
    queryset = models.MyModel.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data = MyModelSerializer(data=self.request.data)
        if data.is_valid():
            return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(data.data['name'])
        return models.MyModel.objects.none()

    def post(self, request):
        return self.get(request)
```

But normally you do *not* use POST requests to *retrieve* data, but to create, update or delete data. Usually one uses a *query string* to filter the queryset.

Comment: you are right about the serializer part, i am just making a minimal example to make it easy to read for everyone, i have updated it to something that use the serializer, which should make sense.

Comment: how would i do it if i need to filter by actually sending data (post request)

Comment: @Ghazi: see edit, but POST requests are normally *not* used to *retrieve* data, only to create/delete/update data.